# Cannot ls in FTP from Ubuntu to IIS 6, can from Vista

Tags: ubuntu, iis-6, ftp

I have an IIS 6 server running FTP on the standard port with basic authentication.

If I connect from a Vista machine (command line FTP client) that is not on the corporate network, all works well.

If I connect from an Ubuntu machine also not on the corporate network, I can connect but not do anything else:

```
230 User MyUser logged in. 
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
```

But then any other commands fail:

```
ftp> ls
500 Invalid PORT Command.
ftp: bind: Address already in use
ftp>
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

At the end of the day I'm trying to get Maven to perform a release using FTP to the IIS server.  Solving this is a step down that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want passive ftp with the BSD ftp client in Ubuntu you can 
do this in two ways:

```
ftp -p <host>
pftp <host>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the configuration by default on Vista active or passive mode? What is it on ubuntu? I guess you have to tell explicitly which one you want to use and it solves your problem.

Comment: If I'm seeing it right, Vista is Active.  How do you tell on Ubuntu, and how do you change the default?